# How to pass data child component to parent component in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I have created example in which data passing to parent to child and parent component vise-versa. So parent to child data sending is completed. But it didn't pass data child to parent component. I have used EventEmitter class into child.

[image: error shows in browser devlopers tools]

[image: code]

Comment: Please read the help section on how to ask questions.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney if you have capability then solve it. i appreciate your down vote.

Answer (score 2):

parent template： ...

```
<child [value]="value" (childEvent) = "parenFunction($event)">  </child>

 //...

  export class ParenComponent{

     value: any={};

    ParenFunction(){

      console.log(value);

  }

}
```

child

```
<p (click) = "clickThis"> click </p>
//...
@Output() childEvent = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
clickThis(){

this.childEvent.emit();
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful to add some kind of explanation as to why this fixes the problem.

Comment: @Toby  i'm so sorry that my English is poor.  i can't write to much

Answer (score 0):

Just like the error states...

> co.onChange is not a function

Well the error is correct, it is not a function. Your name for the function does not match the name in the component. In template you have `onChange` and in component `onchange`, so you need to change either.

Your child component looks good otherwise, and I guess you have something like the following in the parent component :)

```
<my-comp (childeve)="getChildeve($event)"></my-comp>

getChildeve(value) {
  console.log(value)
}
```

Comment: problem solved by just reimporting project..... but now question is why it required re-import project...

Comment: Good to hear, but you still had a mismatch of the names, other `onChange` and other `onchange`, so I assume you have made that change of either name now? :)